# How do you force a call to ILineTransformSource.GetLineTransform in a VS extension for a change to a line adornments dimensions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsx

I 'm writing a Visual Studio extension where I'm creating line adornments that need to be resized when the user resizes the code view. I.e. when the user resizes Visual Studio's window width, I modify both the adornment's width and height. I'm handling the `IWpfTextView.LayoutChanged` event and I am resizing my adornments there. To avoid overlapping the adornments with the lines below it, I also implemented ILineTransformSource.GetLineTransform to enlarge the line's height to accommodate the size of the adornment.

However, when I change the dimensions of the adornments (when handling the `IWpfTextView.LayoutChanged` event) I'm **not** getting calls to my ILineTransformSource.GetLineTransform function to resize the line transform. This leaves the adornment overlapping the lines below it. I can't seem to find any way of forcing a call to `ILineTransformSource.GetLineTransform`. (Although, if the user scrolls the view, I do get these calls. But, I don't want to have to force the user to scroll the window to fix a visual glitch.)

Does anyone know of a way to force Visual Studio to call my `ILineTransformSource.GetLineTransform` so that I can resize the line transforms when my adornments change height?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I need to make room for my adornment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the IWpfTextView.DisplayTextLineContainingBufferPosition method - this will force GetLineTransform calls as well.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how I would put a class in place to capture these events when called? I am new to MEF so I have little understanding of what needs to be done here?